# Table data transfer from one Hadoop environment to another Hadoop environment using Hive and schedule it using oozie

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, oozie, oozie-workflow

I'm pretty new to Hadoop environment.. Can anyone help me out on table data transfer from one Hadoop environment (prod) to another Hadoop environment (dev) using hive query and schedule that query using oozie..

Code sample is most appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Comment: why did you use `apache-spark` tag?

Answer (score 0):

When copying Hive tables from one cluster to another you need to do two things:

1. Copy the actual HDFS data.
2. Copy the Hive table metadata.

You can do both of these relatively easily if you leave out more complex use case / considerations such as diff/copy. There is also consider taking a look at https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/08/29/video-captures-glitching-mississippi-voting-machines-flipping-votes/.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to migrate will be

```
    1 Get all files from hdfs .
    2 Copy them in new hdfs 
    3 Run Create table on new
```

.